# ¿Cómo evito guardar un dato que ya existe en la base de datos desde Django?

Tags: python, django

estoy queriendo evitar guardar un dato que ya existe en la Base de Datos, que en este caso es el RFC, y lo que trato es que me retorne un mensaje que el RFC ya existe, porque al parecer me lo sigue guardando;
Este es mi código y estoy utilizando una vista basada en clases de Django:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, Http404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Cliente
from capitalize import first_last_name


# Esta es la vista del formulario para registrar a un Cliente
class FormCliente(TemplateView):
    template_name = "formulario/formulario.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {
            "title_form": "nuevo cliente".title(),
            "h1_form": "registrar cliente".title()
        }
        return context
```

Desde aquí es donde me esta surgiendo el problema:

```
# Esta es la clase para registrar un nuevo Cliente
class CreateCliente(CreateView):
    model = Cliente
    template_name = "formulario/formulario.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            list_rfc = self.model.objects.get(rfc_client=request.POST['rfc'])

            first_name = request.POST['nombre']
            last_name = request.POST['apellidoP'] + " " + request.POST['apellidoM']
            date_birthday = request.POST['date_birthday']
            rfc_client = request.POST['rfc'].upper()
            email = request.POST['email'].lower()
            tel_cel = request.POST['telefono']
            address = request.POST['domicilio']
            description = request.POST['concepto']

            if rfc_client == list_rfc:
                JsonResponse({'message': 'Ya existe un registro con este RFC!'})
                return False

            else:
                datos_cliente = self.model(
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                    date_birthday=date_birthday,
                    rfc_client=rfc_client,
                    email=email,
                    tel_cel=tel_cel,
                    address=address,
                    description=description)

                datos_cliente.save()
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Datos Guardados Correctamente!!!'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí puedes hacer uso de `get_or_create`.

Sería algo así:

```
datos_cliente, created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(
    rfc_client=request.POST['rfc'],
    defaults={
        'first_name': first_name,
        'last_name': last_name,
        'address': address,
        ...
    }
)
```

Como ves, el `get_or_create` devuelve un par de resultados, el objeto y un booleano que te dice si se ha creado el objeto (`created` = True) o ya existía (`created = False`).